# Bitmask Design Patterns

Tags: design-patterns

I'm curious if there are any rules of thumbs or design patterns on when to use bitmasks to help improve code readability and/or maintainability.

One place I've seen them in the wild is when there are a few or more configuration parameters that need to be passed into a function.

I'm coming at this from an OOP perspective but the answer need not be constrained just to OOP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think bitmasks are mostly to improve time and space performance. From an OOP standpoint, whatever they represent can be encapsulated in a proper interface. In C#, you can take a look at [flags enums](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229062.aspx) for a convenient way to represent them as enumerations.

To pass configuration parameters to a method, I usually prefer creating a class. This way, you can have parameters that are more than just flags, and the client doesn't need to worry about bitwise operations. Take a look at the [`XmlWriterSettings` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwritersettings.aspx) for an example. For an example of a flags enum, look at the [`RegexOptions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.aspx) class.